# Python BeautifulSoup can't find <tr> tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get data with BeautifulSoup module but I cannot get the tag I want from the website, returns None, also I don't want to use **Selenium**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs



site = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries"

r = requests.get(site)

soup = bs(r.text,"html.parser")

ct = soup.find("table",id="main_table_countries_today")

ct2 = ct.find("tr",class_="total_row_world odd")
print(ct2)
```

Comment: The element in question is generated by Javascript, so you can't access it using bs4. Try using a library that runs JS like selenium or pyppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such class as `total_row_world odd` in the `ct` but a class `total_row_world`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

site = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries"
r = requests.get(site)
soup = bs(r.text,"html.parser")

ct = soup.find("table",id="main_table_countries_today")
ct2 = ct.find("tr",class_="total_row_world")
print(ct2)
```

**EDIT**:

Upon investigating deeper, it looks like you need a tool like `selenium` to get the dynamic data that you're looking for:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
site = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries"
driver.get(site)

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

ct = soup.find("table",id="main_table_countries_today")
ct2 = ct.find("tr",class_="total_row_world odd")
print(ct2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
<tr class="total_row_world odd" role="row">
<td></td>
<td style="text-align:left;">World</td>
<td class="sorting_1">24,858,356</td>
<td>+242,396</td>
<td>839,702</td>
<td>+4,736</td>
<td>17,224,364</td>
<td>6,794,290</td>
<td>61,529</td>
<td>3,189</td>
<td>107.7</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td data-continent="all" style="display:none">All</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thank you, but how can I see this data properly? because when I run this code looking badly, I want to see as a line, and I don't want to use Selenium

Comment: @muratgulcan you could iterate over the `ct2` look for `td` tags and print their `text`

Comment: td does not have any class or id name, how can I do?

Comment: find by `tag` and not any class or id.